# Correct ratio of positive to negative training examples for training a random forest-based binary classifier

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

I realized that the related question [Positives/negatives proportion in train set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10734401/positives-negatives-proportion-in-train-set) suggested that a 1-to-1 ratio of positive to negative training examples is favorable for the Rocchio algorithm.

However, this question differs from the related question in that it concerns a random forest model and also in the following two ways.

1) I have plenty of training data to work with, and the main bottleneck on using more training examples is training iteration time. That is, I'd prefer not to take more than a night to train one ranker because I want to iterate quickly.

2) In practice, the classifier will probably see 1 positive example for every 4 negative examples.

In this situation, should I train using more negative examples than positive examples, or still equal numbers of positive and negative examples?

Answer (score 6):

See the section titled "Balancing prediction error" from the official documentation on random forests here: https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~breiman/RandomForests/cc_home.htm#balance

I marked some parts in bold.

In summary, this seems to suggest that your training and test data should either

1. reflect the 1:4 ratio of classes that your real-life data will have
   or
2. you can have a 1:1 mix, but then you should carefully adjust the
   weights per class as demonstrated below till the OOB error rate on
   your desired (smaller) class is lowered

Hope that helps.

> In some data sets, the prediction error between classes is highly
>   unbalanced. Some classes have a low prediction error, others a high.
>   This occurs usually when one class is much larger than another. Then
>   random forests, trying to minimize overall error rate, will keep the
>   error rate low on the large class while letting the smaller classes
>   have a larger error rate. For instance, in drug discovery, where a
>   given molecule is classified as active or not, it is common to have
>   the actives outnumbered by 10 to 1, up to 100 to 1. **In these
>   situations the error rate on the interesting class (actives) will be
>   very high.**
>
> The user can detect the imbalance by outputs the error rates for the
>   individual classes. To illustrate 20 dimensional synthetic data is
>   used. Class 1 occurs in one spherical Gaussian, class 2 on another. A
>   training set of 1000 class 1's and 50 class 2's is generated, together
>   with a test set of 5000 class 1's and 250 class 2's.
>
> The final output of a forest of 500 trees on this data is:
>
> 500 3.7 0.0 78.4
>
> There is a low overall test set error (3.73%) but class 2 has over 3/4
>   of its cases misclassified.
>
> **The error balancing can be done by setting different weights for
>   the classes.**
>
> **The higher the weight a class is given, the more its error rate is
>   decreased. A guide as to what weights to give is to make them
>   inversely proportional to the class populations.** So set weights to 1
>   on class 1, and 20 on class 2, and run again. The output is:
>
> 500 12.1 12.7 0.0
>
> The weight of 20 on class 2 is too high. Set it to 10 and try again,
>   getting:
>
> 500 4.3 4.2 5.2
>
> This is pretty close to balance. If exact balance is wanted, the
>   weight on class 2 could be jiggled around a bit more.
>
> Note that in getting this balance, the overall error rate went up.
>   This is the usual result - to get better balance, the overall error
>   rate will be increased.

Answer (score 3):

This might seem like a trivial answer but the best thing I can suggest is to try on a small subset of your data (small enough that the algorithm trains quickly), and observe what you accuracy is when you use 1-1, 1-2, 1-3 etc...

Plot the results as you gradually increase the total amount of examples for each ratio and see how the performance responds. Very often you'll find that fractions of the data get very close to the performance of training on the full dataset, in which case you can make an informed decision to your question.

Hope that helps.